# How to pull individual information from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I'm doing an array with Object Orientation and method creation for JavaScript and I have a question:

I made it where all of the employees display when clicking the "Show Employees" button including all of their info (It's all fictionalized by the way), however, I am having difficulties with pulling individual user's information, how do I go about clicking on an individual user and pulling only that information?

the function = showEmployee(); is where I am having the issue.

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Lab 9-1: Employee Database</title>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    
  // Complete the employeeObject constructor
  // Remember t o add a method called showEmployee
  function employeeObject(name,department,extension) {[]
    this.name = name;
    this.department=department;
    this.extension=extension;
    this.showEmployee=showEmployee;
    }

      // Instantiate 3 instances of employeeObject
  // Important - Start your array index numbers with 1
      var employees = new Array();
    employees[0] = "Select Employee";
                               employees[1] = new employeeObject("Mai Li", "Sales", 551);
                               employees[2] = new employeeObject("Maria Alvarez", "Human Resources", 441);
                               employees[3] = new employeeObject("Tom Smith", "Marketing", 331);
  
  len = employees.length;
  
    function showEmployee() {   
      var info = ""
        
  // Complete the showEmployee() function
    
    
    
      alert(info);
    
    }
    function showAllEmployees() {
        var info = "";
    for (var i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        info += "Employee: " + employees[i].name + "\n";
        info += "Department: " + employees[i].department +  "\n";
        info += "Extension: " + employees[i].extension + "\n\n";
      }
    
    alert(info);
    }

//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Employee Database</h3>
<hr />
<form name="empForm" id="empForm">
<strong>Select name to view information:</strong> 
<select name="empName" onchange="employees[this.selectedIndex].showEmployee();this.selectedIndex=0;">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if(i == 0) document.write("<option>" + employees[i]) + "</option>";
    else document.write("<option>" + employees[i].name) + "</option>";
  }
  
//
</script>
</select>
<p>
<input type="button" value="Show All Employees" onclick=
"showAllEmployees();" />
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: you can do something very similar to showAllEmployee, just don't use an array and a loop, but only one employee object. As already suggested in an answer, this function should belong to the "class" Employee, and choosing an employee would invoke it, and you naturally have the correct values to show.

Comment: This code should be formatted better as it is hard to read in its current state. Also, it is better style to rename the constructor for an employee to `Employee(name,department,extension)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gotta add value to the `<option>` and pass it's value to the `showEmployee` function. Check out the working snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Lab 9-1: Employee Database</title>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">


        // Complete the employeeObject constructor
        // Remember t o add a method called showEmployee
        function employeeObject(name, department, extension) {
            []
            this.name = name;
            this.department = department;
            this.extension = extension;
            this.showEmployee = showEmployee;
        }

        // Instantiate 3 instances of employeeObject
        // Important - Start your array index numbers with 1
        var employees = new Array();
        employees[0] = "Select Employee";
        employees[1] = new employeeObject("Mai Li", "Sales", 551);
        employees[2] = new employeeObject("Maria Alvarez", "Human Resources", 441);
        employees[3] = new employeeObject("Tom Smith", "Marketing", 331);

        len = employees.length;

        function showEmployee(i) {
            var info = "";
            info += "Employee: " + employees[i].name + "\n";
            info += "Department: " + employees[i].department + "\n";
            info += "Extension: " + employees[i].extension + "\n\n";
            alert(info);
        }

        function showAllEmployees() {
            var info = "";
            for (var i = 1; i < len; i++) {
                info += "Employee: " + employees[i].name + "\n";
                info += "Department: " + employees[i].department + "\n";
                info += "Extension: " + employees[i].extension + "\n\n";
            }

            alert(info);
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Employee Database</h3>
    <hr />
    <form name="empForm" id="empForm">
        <strong>Select name to view information:</strong>
        <select name="empName" onchange="showEmployee(this.value);">
            <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    if (i == 0) document.write('<option value="">' + employees[i]) + "</option>";
                    else document.write('<option value="'+i+'">' + employees[i].name) + "</option>";
                }
            </script>
        </select>
        <p>
            <input type="button" value="Show All Employees" onclick="showAllEmployees();" />
        </p>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider moving the definition of the `showEmployee` method into the constructor definition to put the member variables of an employee in scope.

```js
function employeeObject(name, department, extension) {
    this.name = name;
    this.department = department;
    this.extension = extension;
    this.showEmployee = () => {
        let info = `${this.name}, ${this.department}, ${this.extension}`;
        // or however you wish to format info
        alert(info);
    }
}
```

Working snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Lab 9-1: Employee Database</title>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">


        // Complete the employeeObject constructor
        // Remember t o add a method called showEmployee
        function employeeObject(name, department, extension) {
            this.name = name;
            this.department = department;
            this.extension = extension;
            this.showEmployee = () => {
                let info = `${this.name}, ${this.department}, ${this.extension}`;
                // or however you wish to format info
                alert(info);
            }
        }

        // Instantiate 3 instances of employeeObject
        // Important - Start your array index numbers with 1
        var employees = new Array();
        employees[0] = "Select Employee";
        employees[1] = new employeeObject("Mai Li", "Sales", 551);
        employees[2] = new employeeObject("Maria Alvarez", "Human Resources", 441);
        employees[3] = new employeeObject("Tom Smith", "Marketing", 331);

        len = employees.length;

        function showAllEmployees() {
            var info = "";
            for (var i = 1; i < len; i++) {
                info += "Employee: " + employees[i].name + "\n";
                info += "Department: " + employees[i].department + "\n";
                info += "Extension: " + employees[i].extension + "\n\n";
            }

            alert(info);
        }

//-->
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Employee Database</h3>
    <hr />
    <form name="empForm" id="empForm">
        <strong>Select name to view information:</strong>
        <select name="empName" onchange="employees[this.selectedIndex].showEmployee();this.selectedIndex=0;">
            <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    if (i == 0) document.write("<option>" + employees[i]) + "</option>";
                    else document.write("<option>" + employees[i].name) + "</option>";
                }
            </script>
        </select>
        <p>
            <input type="button" value="Show All Employees" onclick="showAllEmployees();" />
        </p>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe this should be a comment. because it isn't an answer to the question, it is a suggestion to improve code quality and indentation.

Comment: @MarioGarcia I'll move the suggestions for style and formatting to a comment, but the code is still a valid solution to the problem.